# How to modify the comments list in WP & BuddyPress?

Tags: comments, buddypress

I'd like to modify the **comments list** (comments left by users) on WP site using BuddyPress.

In **comments.php** I narrowed it down to the following code:

```
<?php wp_list_comments( array( 'callback' => 'bp_dtheme_blog_comments' ) ); ?>
```

Any clue where I can find **bd_dtheme_blog_comments**, and the best way to modify it?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just search though your source code to find the function definition?

It's in `plugins/buddypress/bp-themes/bp-default/functions.php`, and you can create your own version in your theme that should override the supplied one.